# What is the usage of modifier=chevron on onsen ui list items

Tags: onsen-ui

I am using `onsenui`, there are a lot of examples on the net and `onsen.io` web site as this

```
<ons-list-item modifier="chevron">
```

I just want to know what `modifier` do and what does `modifier="chevron"` mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It just modifies the style of the elements. Here you have an explanation: http://onsen.io/guide/overview.html#UsingModifier

`chevron` adds an arrow to the ons-list-item and slighly changes the style. You have an example of it in the same link, section "Using Sliding Menu".

Comment: Is there a guide somewhere that lists different modifiers and what they do? Or is `"chevron"` something project specific that is defined the project you two are referring to?

Edit: Found it >>  http://components.onsen.io/